# how to change type of column using redbean?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

i am using redbeanphp for database manipulation. i create a table and add a row to my database using this code :

```
$bean= R::dispence("esate") ; 
$bean->import(json_decode($data)) ; 
R::store($bean);
```

in my **$data** variable i have null property ***such as address*** and when redbeanphp store this bean in database set this property type to tinyint or other type.
now when i create another bean with **address** property mysql ignore my value and left **address** column null.

can redbean handle this problem and if answer is YES how ?

Comment: You can always edit the database schema to have the format that you want. redbeanPHP will not change it unless it has to. I also tend to use `FUSE`d models with redbeanPHP so i can always ensure all the bean properties have useful default values by using the 'dispense' method.

Comment: your comment was very useful ..... thank you dear ryan

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$book->title = 'Learn to fly';
$book->rating = 'good';
$book->published = '2015-02-15';
R::store( $book );
```

Comment: i now this method but i would not use this because my table have much more column and it is impossible for me

Comment: Well this one is the only one i know. Try another language?

Comment: what??? another language???? are you kidding me? i create whole of my project with php and now change my language? any way thank you for your suggestion :D

Comment: You don't have to change the whole language. :) You can insert another language in your code.

Comment: Nevermind, i wish i could help you out though. Look through internet, maybe you can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting database schemas on the fly is the core functionality of RedBean, so your question is really surprising.

See:

```
$foo = R::dispense('foo');
$foo->import(array(
    'address' => null,
));
$id = R::store($foo);

$bar = R::dispense('foo');
$bar->import(array(
    'address' => 'baz',
));
$id2 = R::store($bar);

var_dump(R::load('foo', $id)->export());

var_dump(R::load('foo', $id2)->export());
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["address"]=>
  NULL
}
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["address"]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

You've got nothing at all to do for it to work... So the question is what did you do for it **not** to work? In particular, are you sure you haven't [frozen](http://redbeanphp.com/fluid_and_frozen) your database?

Comment: dear rixo my database is not frozen at all... when i create a row with null value for "address" it create a column with tinytext data type and when i add another row with a long address it does not save value of address col in database

Comment: Add your actual code & data to your question, it is most probable that there is an issue in your code that you have not seen... Rather than in RedBean that works as expected, as my example shows.